# JavaScript [Temperature Converter select option]

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

I am creating a Temperature Converter and I am having trouble with it as I am not able to automatically change the output when an option has been selected.

An example of what I want is that the user enters a number into the the text field and and then they will be able to select the current unit for example celsius. Then they will select the unit they want to be outputted. However, I want that if the input value is celsius then the output celsius value should be removed from the output option select menu.

Hope this makes sense :/

Here is the HTML code.

```
<body>
  <h3>Convert Temperature</h3>
<table>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Enter a value</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text">
                <select id ="to">
                    <option value="far">Farhenheight (F°)</option>
                    <option value="cel">Celsius (C°)</option>
                    <option value="kel">Kelvin (K°)</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>To</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" readonly>
                <select id="from">
                    <option value="far">Celsius (C°)</option>
                    <option value="cel">Farhenheight (F°)</option>
                    <option value="kel">Kelvin (K°)</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the JSFiddle link to make things a little clearer.

https://jsfiddle.net/jw6c67vr/4/

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I don't see the part of code where you expect this output option to be hid? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi, I have added it now, however it is not in javascript. It is written of the expected output. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, let me [google that for you](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=hide%20a%20select%20option%20with%20javascript)

Comment: I can see that they use display: none however what if you select another option that isn't the same as the input will it reappear?

Answer (score 0):

I have created the fiddle with your sample demo converting temperature in celsius to temperature in fahrenheit. For others,follow the same procedures.

Below is the js Code:

```
    $('#txtTemperature').on('change', function () {
        var tempValue = $.trim($(this).val());
        var inputUnit = $.trim($('select#to option:selected').val());
        var outputVal = '';
        if (inputUnit === 'cel') {
            outputVal = cel_faren(parseFloat(tempValue));
        }
        $('#txtResult').val(outputVal);
    });
    $('select#to').on('change', function () {
        var options = $("select#to>option").map(function () {
            return $(this).val();
        }).get();
        var unit = $.trim($('option:selected', this).val());
        var outputUnit = $.trim($('select#from option:selected').val());
        if (unit === outputUnit) {
            if ($.inArray(outputUnit, options) > -1) {
                options.splice($.inArray(outputUnit, options), 1);
            }
            $('select#from').val(options[0]);
        }
    });
    function cel_faren(tempInCel) {
        return (tempInCel * (9 / 5) + 32);
    }
```

[Here is the jsfiddl link:](https://jsfiddle.net/shrawanlakhe/jw6c67vr/31/)